# How to create a relationship between two tables in sql?

Tags: database

For instance, I have a table called "country" and another table called "mineral". There is several hundreds countries and probably several thousands types of minerals on their own. At the mean time, every country produces different types of minerals. I need a way to record every country that produces certain types of minerals in one place. What is the best way to realize that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a many-to-many relationship. You could organise this using three tables. One table to record the countries, one table to record the minerals, and another table that links a country to a mineral. So you already have the first two tables, just add the table that links them together:

```
Countries(CountryID, Name, ...)
Minerals(MineralID, Name, ...)
Countries_Mineral(MineralID, CountryID)
```

The table that links them should contain foreign keys, i.e. they point to the primary key in their respective tables.

Comment: Yes, it is a one-to-many relationship. But image there is handreds of countries and thousands of minerals. Therefore, the third table Countries_Mineral would contain probably a million record, which I think is a little awkward. I wonder if there is any other way to achieve that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Woops, I meant many-to-many there. You'd need the intermediate table between the two, I don't believe there is another way. It's not uncommon to have millions of records like this, in fact there are often much more in your average database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a foreign key relationship for this, its very easily achievable if you are using a n sql mager such as phpmyadmin, you get it in structure/relational view